# How to print in console from d3 function

Tags: javascript, d3.js

So I have this function to draw let's say rectangles:

```
draw(data) {
    this.canvas.selectAll('rect')
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append('rect')
        .attr('x', (d) => d.x)
        .attr('y', (d) => d.y)
        .attr('width', (d) => d.width)
        .attr('height', (d) => d.height)
        .style('fill', (d) => d.color);
}
```

and I want to print in console d.x and d.y. I wrote this function:

```
printData(data) {
    this.canvas.selectAll('rect')
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append('rect')
        .attr('x', function(d) { console.log(d.x); });
}
```

but it isn't printing anything in console. Can anybody help me to tell what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're calling `printData` right after `draw`. If that's the case, you're not seeing anything because your "enter" selection is empty (hence nothing after `enter()` will be called).

The solution, that being the case, is just moving the `console.log` to `draw` or using an `each()` in `printData`:

```
printData(data) {
    this.canvas.selectAll('rect')
        .each(function(d) { 
            console.log(d.x); 
        });
}
```